# TypeScript で文字列と数値の加算（連結）を禁止か検出したい

Tags: typescript, tslint

`+` 演算子に文字列と数値を与えると、TypeScript でも JavaScript と同じように、数値が文字列に変換され、連結されます。

```
console.log( "123" + 456 )
// 出力 -> 123456
```

これを禁止するか、検出して警告を出すような事はできないでしょうか。
例えば、 `*` 演算子では文字列から数値への暗黙の型変換が行なわれず、コンパイル時にエラーになります。

```
console.log( "123" * 456 )
// JavaScript: 出力 -> 56088
// TypeScript: コンパイルエラー ->
//     add_str_num.ts(5,14): error TS2362:
//     The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any',
//     'number' or an enum type
```

また、`+` 演算子以外でも暗黙の型変換のような事が行なわれる操作があるのなら、それも禁止したいです。

Comment: TypeScript の spec.md (ver.1.8) の ["4.19.2 The + operator"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#4.19.2) によると、`+` 自体は片方が String 型、他方が Number 型であることを許容しているようです。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TSの機能としては見つけられませんでしたが、tslintならばそれっぽいルールが有りました。
 `restrict-plus-operands` です。

ルールのテスト例： https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/test/rules/restrict-plus-operands/test.ts.lint

Comment: `tslint.json` に `"restrict-plus-operands": true` を指定し、`tslint --type-check --project tsconfig.json foo.ts` とする事でエラーにする事ができました。変数同士であってもエラーになり、型情報を利用できています。ありがとうございました。